# When is a groupoid the path groupoid of a graph?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I am actually interested in the $C^*$-algebras, so perhaps my question should be: How can you recognize whether a $C^*$-algebra $A$ is isomorphic to $C^*(\Lambda)$ for some (higher-rank) graph $\Lambda$, if $A$ is not presented to you via the Cuntz-Krieger relations?

Comment: I'm aware of the work of Drinen, showing that any AF algebra is a graph C*-algebra; I'm asking if anyone knows of more general results along those lines.

Comment: Hi Elizabeth, I think it would be better if the question in the title and the actual question coincided.

Answer (score 5):

This is an answer to the question: *"Given a $C^\ast$-algebra $A$ that shares some properties of (higher-rank) graph algebras (such as separability, nuclearity, UCT, K-theoretic properties), can I conclude that $A$ **is** a (higher-rank) graph algebra?"*

My answer is: this would require a classification of the class of $C^\ast$-algebras in question together with a description of the range of the classifying invariant on (higher-rank) graph algebras. This problem is open, even for purely infinite Cuntz--Krieger algebras; see [*Do phantom Cuntz-Krieger algebras exist?*](http://arxiv.org/abs/1210.6515) (Edit: this case was solved in http://arxiv.org/abs/1511.09463.)

In the simple purely infinite case, one can say the following: a unital UCT Kirchberg algebra $A$ is a graph algebra if and only if $K_1(A)$ is free. This theorem is due to Wojciech Szymanski.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an incomplete answer, which I hope can be completed by others; therefore, I will make it CW, and invite others to add to it.

A groupoid is the path groupoid of a graph iff it is equivalent as a groupoid to a disjoint union of wedges of circles.  Put another way, every groupoid is classified up to equivalence by a list (up to permutations) of groups, namely the fundamental groups of each component; a groupoid is the path groupoid of a graph iff every group on the list is a free group.

So one answer to your question might be: work out what all the fundamental groups are, and whether they are free.

This is not necessarily that easy.  Without knowing more, I would expect that it is a very hard question of deciding whether some random group is free.